# Format string inside sql query when use stored procedure in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query inside my stored procedure:

```
IF @backup = 0
    BEGIN
       SELECT sql = 'BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK="'+@file+'"';
    END
```

`@file` is `nvarchar(MAX)` and `backup` is `int`.

If I execute the stored procedure like:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_cp_backup_restore_db]
        @backup = 0,
        @file = N'C:\backupFiles\MyDatabase.bak'
```

but the result becomes:
`BACKUP DATABASE ContentPlatform TO DISK="C:\backupFiles\MyDatabase.bak"`

I want to appear `BACKUP DATABASE ContentPlatform TO DISK='C:\backupFiles\MyDatabase.bak'`
because the correct format is

```
BACKUP
DATABASE MyDatabase TO
DISK='C:\MyDatabase.bak'
```

accordingly with http://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/sql-serverexclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-because-the-database-is-in-usethe-tail-of-the-log-for-the-database-has-not-been-backed-up/

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `"` in your initial strings, use `''` instead.  SQL knows, if you put two `'` next to each other, that you mean `'` to appear in the string *(as opposed to ending one string and starting another.)*

```
SELECT sql = 'BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK='''+@file+'''';
```

It looks odd, sure, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sql = 'BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK='''+@file+''''
```

Comment: Then will becomes `BACKUP DATABASE ContentPlatform TO DISK=@file`

Comment: This is wrong.  You can't put `'` in a string with just `'`.  That will terminate the string.  You need `''` instead *(for each `'` that you want in your string)*.